# Ruby on Rails app on Heroku file upload not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, file-upload

I'm new to Rails and Heroku as well.

Following tutorials I succeed to upload my app to Heroku.

My app is enable us to upload csv file to *uploads* folder in *public*.
So I can upload file in heroku deployed app and show table as I want.

But after 30 mins or so those files are removed automatically and showing error that no such file in public/uploads folder.

It is properly working on my local which is using sqlite3.

But heroku want to use psql for production mode so I changed production mode to use psql.

So if I upload csv file then it is stored in 'public/uploads' folder.

I think heroku app is automatically update to github repo even I didn't execute 'git push heroku master' command.

In my local repository files are stored but they are run on development mode.

How can I make upload functionality fully working?

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: When using Heroku (or any hosting service) you need to upload to a bucket store like Amazon S3. It's easiest to do that using an attachment gem like Paperclip. Heroku has good docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3).

Answer (score 1):

[Ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) is just the way heroku works, as explained in the article - uploaded files will be removed when the instance is restarted.

What you should do is to upload those files for example to S3 (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3), you can achieve this with CarrierWave gem with Fog gem but there are other possibilities as explained in this thread here: https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/2k9sq4/heroku_any_files_you_upload_will_not_be_saved/